# ReactJS - jest test error 'unexpected token ...'

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am trying to run jest tests after switching to laptop. Before, on computer every test was launching and no syntax/runtime errors were returned, but now when I try to run them on laptop, they return me error:

```
C:\PROJECT_DIR\foo.test.js
      ...initialState,
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:318:17)
```

What could cause this? I did `npm install`, everything is installed, and yet I keep getting this error even though it did not occur on previous machine.

This is the test:

```
import increments from '../increments'

const initialState = {
  goldBase: 0,
  goldMulti: 1,
  goldIncr: 0,
  coalBase: 0,
  coalMulti: 1,
  coalIncr: 0,
  ironBase: 0,
  ironMulti: 1,
  ironIncr: 0,
  stoneBase: 0,
  stoneMulti: 1,
  stoneIncr: 0,
  woodBase: 0,
  woodMulti: 1,
  woodIncr: 0,
  foodBase: 0,
  foodMulti: 1,
  foodIncr: 0
}

describe('increments', () => {
  it('should properly increment values of base increments', () =>  {
    const action = {
      type: 'INCREMENT',
      goldBase: 1,
      coalBase: 0.2,
      ironBase: 0.8,
      stoneBase: NaN,
      woodBase: undefined,
      foodBase: null
    };

    const testState = {
      ...initialState,
      coalBase: 0.1
    };

    const expectedState = {
      ...initialState,
      goldBase: 1,
      coalBase: 0.3,
      ironBase: 0.8,
    };
    expect(increments(testState, action)).toEqual(expectedState);
  });
```

And here is `package.json`:

```
 {
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^22.1.4"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So that syntax comes from the [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) plugin which is part of babel (which I see you have), but it looks like you don't have this specific plugin. As such, whatever JS engine jest is using probably doesn't know how to interpret the spread (...) syntax.

Try adding the plugin to your project and enabling it, and see if it works then!

Comment: Thanks! It really solved the job, although I am still curious why it happens that on one computer, such plugin line wasn't needed and on the other it solves that very problem, do you happen to have any insight on that?

Comment: So jest is something that's installed with NPM. To get NPM, you have to install node, as NPM is Node's Package Manger. Node then provides the environment that javascript "runs" in. Based on that, I would guess that the version of node (and thus the version of chromes v8 javascript compiler) is different on the two computers. You can check that by running `node --version` on the two computers.